# What is `build agent folder` $(SourceDir) of a build definition in TFS Build 2012?

Tags: tfsbuild, build-definition

When creating a `build definition` for a TFS build, there is a section called `Source Settings` as below snapshoot where we have to define 1) Source Control Folder and 2) Build Agent Folder.

As I understand, the `source control folder` is where to get the source to build. But I don't get the idea what is the `build agent folder` is used for in a build.

Please share me what that is about if you know it. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Directory on the Build machine , which will be used for  "check out" your source code from TFS , Compiled and Build

Comment: @SurjitSamra And what does `$(SourceDir)` mean then?

Comment: Added my answer, hopefully it will help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$(SourceDir)` is the Directory on the Build machine, which will be used for Check-out your source code from TFS and then to Compile it and Build.

Value for the $(SourceDir) is what you will configure it to; normally your working directory on the build machine and by default its value come from `Working directory` settings on the `build agent` properties (red marked) option as shown in the picture; i.e. `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)`

Where

- *$(SystemDrive)* is system drive, e.g. C:
- *$(BuldAgentID)* is a numeric number assigned to agents normally 1,2,3 etc.
- *($BuildDefinitionPath)* is the root folder of your source code from TFS.

So a typical example of $(SourceDir) can be "C:\Bulids\1\TeamProjectName\Path\To\Your\App"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got that. Please combined your answer into a full-detail one so as I get yours as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: $(SourceDir) does not exist in TFS 2015, found $(Build.SourcesDirectory) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`Build Agent` host `WWF (sequential workflow)` and execute all activities on source.

When you set `Build Agent Folder to $(SourceDir)`, agent use `Working Directory` in order to retrieve source.

When you set Agent Folder to another folder, agent retrieve source from this folder

Comment: To retrieve the source? I guess source retrieve trong the `source control folder`